# What is the Rust equivalent of C# System.DateTime.Ticks?

Tags: datetime, rust

In C#, I can do something like this:

```cs
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-08 10:00");
Console.WriteLine(dt.Ticks);
```

Which prints `636536808000000000`, which is:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001
>   (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar)

Is there a way to achieve the same using Rust's `chrono` crate?

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono::offset::FixedOffset;

fn get_ticks() -> u64 {
    let str = "Tue, 1 Jul 2003 10:52:37 +0200";
    let dt = DateTime::<FixedOffset>::parse_from_rfc2822(str).unwrap();
    // Now what?    
}
```

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d1112e8bd8d23600e722342cf2dcd273&version=stable).